# WPF and background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, multithreading

I got a WPF window and i want to do some work in a background thread..

when the work is done i want to do it again.. like a loop with a UI update between

my code:

```
private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            m_stopCamera = false;
            m_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            m_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            m_worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new     RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            m_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

unsafe void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  // my work....
  e.Result = new MyResultClass(p1,p2..);
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
                return;


            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Logger.LogException(e.Error.ToString());
                Window_Closed(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            try
            {

                //UI work..
                DetectionResult result = e.Result as DetectionResult;
                if (result.Cancel == true)
                {
                    m_DetectedObjID = result.DetectionID;
                    // PlaySound();
                    audio_MediaEnded(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                else
                     ((BackgroundWorker)sender).RunWorkerAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Logger.LogException(ex.ToString());
                Window_Closed(this,new EventArgs());
            }

        }
```

I know this code isn't good cause i got a threading hell and can't debug it properly

for example.. when the code is running and i click the close button i can see in the event
the the worker is busy all the time.. resulting an infinity loop..

```
 private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (m_worker.IsBusy)
                    m_worker.CancelAsync();

                while(m_worker.IsBusy);
                base.Close();
            }

        }
```

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Could you show how do you handle pending cancellation in you `worker_DoWork` method?

Comment: I dont handle it.. only in the RunWorkerCompleted event

Comment: Read my answer below. You need to set `e.Cancelled` to `true` by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you don't ever mark your work as cancelled in `worker_DoWork`. Cancellation code in that method should look like the following:

```
if ((m_worker.CancellationPending == true))
{
   e.Cancel = true;
   return;
}
```

Only after that you'll get `e.Cancelled==true` in completion handler and your loop will stop.

---

If you think that calling `CancelAsync()` should set Cancelled to true, you're wrong. Here is decompiled code from BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync():

```
public void CancelAsync()
{
  if (!this.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("BackgroundWorker_WorkerDoesntSupportCancellation"));
  this.cancellationPending = true;
}
```

As you can see it just sets `CancellationPending` to true, nothing more. So, you have to check this property in your `worker_DoWork` as shown in the first snippet.

Comment: Thanks, i added it, but it didn't fix my problem..

when the window is close i return to the parent window
window2.ShowDialog();..
only after the window has been closed the background thread has stopped.

The crash come only after i call window2.ShowDialog() for the second time..

maybe the problem isn't in the background thread , but in the window navigation..

what do you think ?

Comment: If so, this crash issue could be completely different and it's better to create another question.

Comment: thanks, you are right. i had to dispose something in the window that did not dispose itself

Answer (score 1):

clear line :

```
while(m_worker.IsBusy);//may be go to infinite loop
```

Comment: This line is only for debug.. what happens is that i'm back to the previous window but the background thread is active..

<pre>
Window window = new Window2(selectedTitle, m_selectedCamID);
window.Owner = this;
window.ShowDialog();
<code>

after the the ShowDialog the debugger jump back to the background thread in window2's code

Comment: @RedHat: It's obvious that infinite loop is at that line. The question was - why?

Comment: CancelAsync() Requests cancellation of a pending background operation, and may be little time wait to cancel completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something in the background, you can use this:

```
public void DoEvents()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        code;
        DoEvents();
    }));
}
```

The code will be executed when the CPU will be free, so it doesn't affect performance of your main thread.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke will affect the performance, maybe not of the mainthread but of the workthread so he should use the [ReportProgress-Methode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.90).aspx) if he want's to show some sort of progress